# C++ class wrapper for C struct

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct, wrapper

I want to write an c++ class that wraps a c struct. Here is a simple *example* for a c struct:

```
struct POINT {
  long x;
  long y;
}
```

Now I am assuming this following class, but I am not sure if it is "performant" nor good c++ style. I didnt want to use a unnecessary variable or function call. It would be very nice if you improve my code :).

The basic idea behind this class is that it is just a wrapper/ handler for the struct. Thats why `setStruct` and `getStruct` can modify the private data directly and that it is just a pointer. The other members are always named `set<Attribute>` and `get<Attribute>`.

If you use `setStruct` the only disadvantage I can think of is that the struct could be delete due to scopes so that the pointer is "invalid".

```
namespace wrapper {
class POINT {
  ::POINT * POINT_;

public:
  POINT() {
    POINT_ = new ::POINT;
  }
  ~POINT() {
    delete POINT_;
  }
  inline void setX( long x ) {
    POINT_->x = x;
  }
  inline long getX() {
    return POINT_->x;
  }
  inline void setY( long y ) {
    POINT_->y = y;
  }
  inline long getY() {
    return POINT_->y;
  }
  inline void setStruct(::POINT * __POINT) {
    POINT_ = __POINT;
  }
  inline ::POINT * getStruct() {
    return POINT_;
  }
};
}
```

Comment: Why not just hold 2 LONG member variables and define an implicit conversion operator to POINT ? Also theres absolutely no reason to hold a pointer to a ::POINT instead of the ::POINT itself.

Comment: `_POINT` is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Also, never use `new` except maybe in `std::make_unique` until C++14 or unless you're the 1% who actually has a specific scenario where it is a must.

Comment: learn about pimpl idiom so as to use ur already POINT struct in implementation file(.cpp)

Comment: @Borgleader: The idea behind it is that `setStruct` wouldnt copy only the pointer and not the whole memory.
@chris: Is that why there are a lot people writing `<class>_`? How can I avoid using `new`?

Comment: Copying one pointer or 2 longs is about the same in terms of performance. You're micro-optimizing.

Comment: @Borgleader: This is just an example. In reality there are a few more bytes (about 14 to 45). I know that there is only a short delay but is is more optimized, is it?

Comment: Like I said, you're prematurely optimizing and in doing so making your code less obvious. Express your ideas in the simplest most obvious way and if (AND ONLY IF) it turns out to be a bottleneck, then optimize. (Hint: 99% of the time, it won't be)

Comment: @andrew, Any RAII solution is preferred. In this case, a smart pointer.

Comment: I think this was a simplified example for a larger case.  Suppose instead of "struct POINT" it was "struct BIGDATA" and contained gigabytes.  I think the question was exactly *how* to optimize, not *if*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you may be better off using inheritance instead of composition. It will eliminate the need to manage an additional resource and allow your "wrapper" to act as a POINT instead of requiring accessors and mutators for the entire POINT structure.

```
namespace wrapper {
    class Point : public ::POINT
    {
    public:
        Point() { }
        ~Point() { }

        // The following accessors/mutators may not be necessary.
        // They can however be handy with code that requires a pointer to
        // member function (i.e. transformations)
        void setX(long nx) { x = nx; }
        long getX() { return x; }
        void setY(long ny) { y = ny; }
        long getY() { return y; }

        // copy assignment operators
        Point& operator=(const POINT& p)
        {
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            return *this;
        }

        Point& operator=(const Point& p)
        {
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            return *this;
        }
    };
}
```

If you want to prevent direct access to the members of `POINT` you can use private inheritance. You can also provide a conversion operator to allow implicit conversions from `Point` to `POINT`. This will replace the `POINT* getStruct()` member function but still allow you to easily use it with functions that require `POINT` as an argument.

```
namespace wrapper {
    // Use private inheritance to prevent direct access to the
    // members of POINT
    class Point : private POINT
    {
    public:
        Point() { }
        ~Point() { }

        // Copy constructor
        Point(const ::POINT& p) { x = p.x; y = p.y; }

        // Accessor/mutators
        void setX(long nx) { x = nx; }
        long getX() { return x; }
        void setY(long ny) { y = ny; }
        long getY() { return y; }

        // Allow implicit conversions to POINT* when necessary
        // Replaces getStruct()
        operator ::POINT*() { return this; }
        operator const ::POINT*() const { return this; }

        // Copy assignment operators
        Point& operator=(const POINT& p)
        {
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            return *this;
        }

        Point& operator=(const Point& p)
        {
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
            return *this;
        }
    };
}

extern "C" void someCFunction(POINT *);

int main()
{
    POINT cp;
    wrapper::Point p;

    p.x = 0; // FAIL
    p.setX(0); // OK
    p = cp; // OK

    // No need to call getPoint().
    someCFunction(p);
}
```

---

<sub>Note: I have removed the use of `inline` as they are unnecessary. Functions defined within a class definition are already inline (see $7.1.2/3). Kudos to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) for reminding me.</sub>

Comment: do you really need the setter/getters? you publicly inherited from a struct so I figure the members will also be public?

Comment: I had considered removing them but decided not to. I added a note on why they _may_ still be useful. It's hard to say since I don't know what else the OP is trying to accomplish with the wrapper.

Comment: This is an nice idea. But I would use `private` instead of `public` for inheritance too. Is there an argument against this?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Fair enough.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: My aim would be creating a class that provides a way for handling with c structs without using direct member calling. Anyway, thanks for this nice code :)

Comment: @andrew No argument against private inheritance and I have included an additional example using it along with conversion operators that can replace `getStruct()`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: The second code works very well, thank you :). But the first code allows conversions from `Point` to `POINT`. The second allows only conversions from `Point*` to `POINT*`. Is there a way to convert it "directly"?

Comment: You can't. Those operators shouldn't have been included in the example, sorry. Conversion operators are never considered when converting to a base class or reference of the base class. The only operators that should have been included were to `POINT*` to replace `getStruct()`

Comment: The `inline` markings are redundant when inside the class if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @chris Correct. 7.1.2/3 - A function defined within a class definition is an inline function. I'm having one of _those_ days, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: To convert `Point` to `POINT` I have to use `Point p; POINT p_ = *(POINT *)p;`. This works fine, but writing this all the time is a bit annoying.

Do you think it would be unprofessional, if I would add this member to `Point`?

`POINT convert() { return this; }`

Comment: That will work fine as long as there is no expectation that changes to the returned `POINT` will be reflected in the `Point` object. You can also do `POINT& getPOINT() { return *this; }`

Comment: Is there a way to construct a Point reference from POINT?  (or in other words, interpret a pointer to either as the other?)  I would expect the 2 to have the same memory allocation order and foot print...

Answer (score 0):

As already noted `_POINT` is a reserved name because it starts with `_` + capital letter.

Using all caps for type names is subjective although I tend to steer away from it.

Your class will have all sorts of problems (double delete, delete non-heap memory, and more) if you ever copy it, or pass the address of a stack-based POINT into `setStruct`.

Your class will be much much simpler and less prone to error if you simply compose by value. You save a level of indirection in exchange for copying a bit more data, but chances are the copy will be better cached than an indirection that may have to hit memory twice.

There isn't any real problem with having `getStruct` and `setStruct` functions to translate explicitly to and from the C structure.

However my question here is: What does your C++ wrapper provide you that the C-struct doesn't? You're just providing wrapped methods to the individual attributes anyway rather than some sort of interface that does other operations on the class. In this case I can't actually see a reason to use the wrapper at all (unless you plan to add debugging logic to the getters and setters so you can follow program flow easier).

Comment: I changed `POINT_` to `_POINT`. How can I avoid this problems. Could you please describe it more detailed and give some examples?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes I want to provide more functionality :).