# Changing a macro in C (or C++)

Tags: c++, c, macros

In other words, how can I redefine a macro based on it's previous definition? Specifically, I want to add a string to the end of a string macro in C++. This is what I've tried so far:

```
#define FOO "bla"
// code here will read FOO as "bla"
#define FOO FOO ## "dder"
// code here will read FOO as "bladder"
```

In C++, this returns `error: FOO was not declared in this scope`. How would I do this without getting this error?

EDIT:
I've read the comments and found out what an "XY problem" is. What I want to do is make a library for C but the library is written in C++. Because the library requires Classes to function (because it uses other C++ libraries), I wanted to make an empty class that the C program using the library can add custom properties to using Macro functions. Something like this:

```
// lib.h

#define PROPERTIES ""
#define NEW_PROPERTY(X) // add X + ";\n" to PROPERTIES (somehow)

#ifdef __cplusplus
Class myclass
{
    public:
        PROPERTIES
}
#endif
```

_

```
// c code
#include <lib.h>

NEW_PROPERTY(int id);
NEW_PROPERTY(int color);

int main(){
...
```

The c program won't need to access the properties because they only exist so that a third-party library that is a dependency for my library can use them.

Comment: The C and C++ standards do not provide any such feature. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can't redefine a macro without undefining it first.

Comment: I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Tell us what you really want to achieve by doing this and let us help with that.

Comment: You can't do that directly. But you can have the same effect with **2** macros `FOO1` and `FOO2`. Also note that `##` is **not** to concatenate literal strings (just separate them with a space), but to concatenate *tokens*. So: `#define FOO1 "bla"` `#define FOO2 FOO1 "dder"`

Comment: It is not a good idea! Your `FOO` definition will blow up quickly with some bad includes!!! And you won't be able to find the problem ever!!!
But is it an XY problem? Why do you need it? I think it makes no sense...

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how the langauge works. The macros are just a shorthand to avoid writing something you could write manually. Moreover, TUs (translation units) are compiled separately, so you can't write a macro in a .c file, and expect an unrelated .cpp file to be affected.

Comment: note that you already got an answer for Y and X is a somewhat different question. I would consider to post a new question for X

Comment: In addition, what you try is not to concatenate *literal string*, but some code. Typically for code, the line return is not needed, and the semi colon should be the one after the macro use.

Comment: To get the behavior your edit descirbes, I think the "right" way would be to define a struct on the c side with the properties you desire, and then extend that struct in c++. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454536/c-class-wrapper-for-c-struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

From the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html#Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros) (emphasis is mine):

> However, if an identifier which is currently a macro is redefined, then **the new definition must be effectively the same as the old one**. Two macro definitions are effectively the same if:
>
> - Both are the same type of macro (object- or function-like).
> - All the tokens of the replacement list are the same.
> - If there are any parameters, they are the same.
> - Whitespace appears in the same places in both. It need not be exactly the same amount of whitespace, though. Remember that comments count as whitespace.
>
> These definitions are effectively the same:
>
> ```
> #define FOUR (2 + 2)
> #define FOUR         (2    +    2)
> #define FOUR (2 /* two */ + 2)
> ```
>
> but these are not:
>
> ```
> #define FOUR (2 + 2)
> #define FOUR ( 2+2 )
> #define FOUR (2 * 2)
> #define FOUR(score,and,seven,years,ago) (2 + 2)
> ```
>
> **If a macro is redefined with a definition that is not effectively the same as the old one, the preprocessor issues a warning and changes the macro to use the new definition.** If the new definition is effectively the same, the redefinition is silently ignored. This allows, for instance, two different  headers to define a common macro. The preprocessor will only complain if the definitions do not match.

Comment: the docs you quote dont exclude to `#undef` then `#define` as something else

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number true, but to move information out of a previous macro def into a new one is not possible given the c macro semantics without redefining. https://pastebin.com/8LSSPN9s is invalid under section 3.1 of those docs